# Adding new DataFrame column with age, having birth dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame with a column named BOD:

```
0       1958-04-14
1       1954-02-28
2       1955-04-01
3       1955-08-28
4       1955-09-06
```

`Name: BOD, Length: 10768, dtype: datetime64[ns]`

And I need to create a new column ('age') calculating the age of each row. I had some problems with formats and couldnt do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post [mre] of your code. Also check [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What is your expected output? (also can be really annoying if you need to require calendar year subtraction, such that someone born March 12th 1921 is still considered 99)

Comment: What format did you want your age to be in?  Years?  Days?

Comment: `df.assign(age=pd.Timestamp('now') - df.BOD)`

Comment: @piRSquared has worked! The only problem is that gaves me the age in days. How can I change it to just years? Thanks!

Comment: Follow the link to the duped question.  Your answer is there.